# What is switch over time in LACP(Link aggregation control protocol)

Tags: networking

This  is question have been asked in one of the interview and I couldn't answer it .Its a particular to LACP protocol.I googled a lot still not able to find the answer.

Can anybody what's this SWITCH OVER time in LACP?

Answer (score 0):

LACP protocol must have some interval, in which send via line a LACP control packet, which tested, if this physical interface is up (like a ping ICMP packet). If it don't get reply for this packet, it know, that this interface is down and has to be disabled from "channel", which is managed by LACP protocol.

I think, that `switch over time` you asked is that interval, because after this time LACP know, that this line is down and can switch to another one, which is up.